Abundancia de Especies Silvestres a Partir de Fototrampeo
Buenos días/tardes/noches
A continuación, comento un poco mi situación:
Actualmente me encuentro trabajando con datos de fototrampeo de un área protegida, al momento ya tengo inidentificadas las especies de fauna silvestre, ya generé una tabla de datos en formato .csv a partir de los datos de las imágenes recogidas. Lo que se me solicita actualmente es hacer un estudio de abundancia de cada una de las especies presentes, no puedo utilizar directamente la tabla de datos que ya tengo, porque los datos que me proporciona son de "eventos de muestreo" o frecuencia de actividad de cada especie; lo que estaba pensando para estimar la abundancia de las especies era considerar los datos de las imágenes sean múltiplos de 3, así de esta forma (y considerando la programación de las cámaras trampa) hago una relaciona entre "eventos de muestreo" y la abundancia relativa de las especies. Mi dificultad esta en no poder filtrar la información, no se como podría ser el código que me permita extraer la información en múltiplos de 3, ya sea de la base de datos o directamente desde las imágenes.
Adjunto el código que use hasta el momento:
library(camtrapR)
library(readxl)
Sys.which("exiftool")

tc<- read_excel("Modelo_Excel_Trampas.xls")

fototrampeo_tc <-file.path('tc')

fototrampeo_tc_carpeta <- createStationFolders (inDir = fototrampeo_tc, stations = as.character (tc$Station),createinDir = TRUE)

especies<- c("Vaca","Perro","Zorro Patas Negras","Socri Patas Negras","Zorrino","Pinzon Cresta Roja","Perdiz Tataupa","Suso","Conejo de los Palos","Aramadillo Amarillo","Tiluchi","Gato Montes","Palomas","Zorro Patas Amarillas","Urina","Oso Bandera","Charata","Pecari Solitario","Cacholote Marron","Puma","Reptil","Raton","Caracara","Cerdo Domestico","Tamandua","Anta","Pecari Labios Blancos","Bandurria baya","Zorzal Vientre Cremoso")

carpeta_especies_tc <- createSpeciesFolders(inDir = fototrampeo_tc,species = especies, hasCameraFolders = FALSE,removeFolders = FALSE)

tabla_especies_tc <- recordTable(inDir = fototrampeo_tc,IDfrom = 'directory',timeZone = 'America/Mexico_City',removeDuplicateRecords = FALSE,writecsv = FALSE)

head(tabla_especies_tc)

options(max.print = 10000)

library(sp)

write.csv(tabla_especies_tc, 'tabla especies tc.csv')

tabla_indepen_tc <- recordTable(inDir = fototrampeo_tc, IDfrom = 'directory', minDeltaTime = 30, deltaTimeComparedTo = 'lastRecord',timeZone = 'America/Mexico_City',exclude = 'NA')

write.csv(tabla_especies_tc, "tabla especies Irenda.csv")
write.csv(tabla_indepen_tc, "tabla independientes Irenda.csv")

Espero puedan ayudarme, o si tienen alguna sugerencia les estaría muy agradecido, y si se necesita que aclare algo que pueda ayudar quedo atento.
Muchas gracias, van a disculpar soy bastante nuevo en este tema.

¡Hola!
Escribo aquí la respuesta porque es más larga que un comentario, aunque en realidad no termino de comprender bien lo que planteas.
Hay un momento en el que sugieres coger sólo las imágenes que son múltiplo de 3, ¿cierto?
Suponiendo que tienes a imágenes, para coger las número 3, 6, 9, . . . hasta llegar al múltiplo de 3 menor que dicho valor, puedes utilizar la secuencia siguiente:
3*(1:abs(a/3))

Ejemplo
# Definir el número de imágenes
  a <- 50
# Secuencia de imágenes a seleccionar (múltiplos de 3)
  idx <- 3*(1:abs(a/3))
  idx
[1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48

# Selección de los datos de la tabla (df) suponiendo que la información está en filas
  new.df <- df[idx,]


Hola! muchas gracias por el apoyo
si, mas o menos lo que estoy necesitando, ahora para sistematizar la información después de aplicar el código que sugiere, lo puedo poner todo en un data.frame no? para generar una nueva tabla

Sí, acabao de editar la respuesta, ahora en new.df se incluyen los datos seleccionados (suponiendo que la información estaba en filas).
